# Central limit problem. Maximizing profit when overbooking flights.

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

> In order to avoid empty seats on an airplane, an airline will sell more seats (tickets) than available on the flight well aware of the risk of having to compensate passengers that have been overbooked. Suppose on some flight there are $S=555$ seats available. The revenue for every passenger is $\alpha=2659\$$. The cost for compensating an overbooked passenger is $\beta=600\$$. Every person that has booked a flight will turn up with a probability $p$ (independent of every other person). Assume if they don't show up to a flight they don't have to pay. Use the normal approximation to calculate how many tickets the airline needs to sell to maximize profit for the case that $p=0.95$ and $p=0.873$. Let $P_n$ be the profit and $S_n$ the passengers (people that showed up and are on the plane) and $n$  the sold tickets. Hint: Show that: $$E[P_{n+1}-P_n]\ge 0 \iff P(S_n<S)\ge \frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}$$

**Edit:** The problem I am having is the following: How does
$$E\big[S_{n+1}-S_n \big]=P(S_n<S) ?$$

I just wanted to include the rest for context.

**What I have done so far:** As far as I understand there are two parts to this problem. The first part is showing that the two inequalities are equivalent and that the expected profit from the $n+1$ sold ticket is zero or positive. The second part is using the central limit theorem (CLT) to determine what $n$ actually is. I will start with the second part which I think I have gotten right (please correct me if I made a mistake) and then I will show the first part because that's where I am having difficulties.

---

Since the r.v. are independent and bernoulli, the sum $S_n$ has mean $p$ and variance $p(1-p)$. Therefore ,

$$\begin{equation*}\begin{split}P\left(S_n \le S\right)&=P(S_n \le 555)\ge\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta}\\[10pt] &\iff P\left( \frac{S_n-np}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{p(1-p)}}\le\frac{555-np}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{p(1-p)}}\right)\ge\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta} \\[10pt] &\iff P\left( \frac{S_n-0.95n}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{0.95(0.05)}}\le\frac{555-0.95n}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{0.95(0.05)}}\right)\ge\frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta} \\[10pt] &\iff 
 P\left(Z_n \le \frac{555-0.95n}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{0.95(0.05)}}\right)\ge\frac{600}{3259}\end{split}\end{equation*}$$

I looked up the Z-score for a P-value of $\frac{600}{3259}$ which is $0.89983$.

$$\begin{align}&\implies \frac{555-0.95n}{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{0.95(0.05)}}=0.89983 \\[10pt] &\iff n\approx 583.188 \end{align}$$

So to maximize profit (if the equivalence relation above is true) the airline needs to sell $583$ or $584$ tickets.

---

Showing the equivalence of the inequalities:

$$\begin{equation*}\begin{split} \text{Profit}&= \text{Revenue}-\text{Cost} \\[10pt] P_n&=S_n \alpha-(n-S_n)\beta \\[10pt] P_n&= S_n(\alpha+\beta)-n\beta \\[10pt] \implies P_{n+1} &=S_{n+1}(\alpha+\beta)-(n+1)\beta\end{split} \end{equation*}$$

Therefore,

$$\begin{equation*}\begin{split} P_{n+1}-P_{n}&=S_{n+1}(\alpha+\beta)-(n+1)\beta-\Big(S_n(\alpha+\beta)-n\beta \Big) \\[10pt] \iff P_{n+1}-P_n &=(S_{n+1}-S_n)(\alpha+\beta)-\beta \\[10pt] \iff E\big[ P_{n+1}-P_{n}\big] &= E\big[ (S_{n+1}-S_n)(\alpha+\beta)-\beta \big]\end{split} \end{equation*}$$

Since I want $E\big[ P_{n+1}-P_{n}\big] \ge 0$ it follow that:

$$\begin{equation*}\begin{split} &\implies E\big[ (S_{n+1}-S_n)(\alpha+\beta)-\beta \big] \ge 0 \\[10pt] &\iff E\big[ (S_{n+1}-S_n)(\alpha+\beta) \big] -E\big[\beta \big] \ge 0 \\[10pt] 
 &\iff E\big[ S_{n+1}-S_n) \big] (\alpha+\beta)-\beta \ge 0 \\[10pt] &\iff E\big[ S_{n+1}-S_n \big] \ge \frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta} \\  \color{red}{\vdots} \\ &\iff \color{red}{P(S_n < S)}\ge \frac{\beta}{\alpha+\beta} \end{split} \end{equation*}$$

I feel like I am very close but I can't see how the expected value turns into this probability? What am I missing? In other words how does:

$$E\big[S_{n+1}-S_n \big]=P(S_n<S) ?$$

Comment: Looks hard. Consider posting on MathOverflow.

Comment: *newsvendor problem*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused by the definitions of $n$ and $S_n$, but it seems $S_n$ is the number of people that get to board the plane, and $n-S_n$ is the number of overbooked passengers that need to be compensated. Or in other words, $S_n = \min\{n, S\}$.

In particular, either two things can happen:

- $S_n < S$, which is equivalent to $S_n = n < S$, in which case we have $S_{n+1} - S_n = (n+1) - n = 1$
- $S_n = S$, in which case $S_{n+1} - S_n = S - S = 0$.

Thus,
$$E[S_{n+1} - S_n]
= E[(S_{n+1} - S_n)\mathbf{1}_{S_n < S}]
+ E[(S_{n+1} - S_n)\mathbf{1}_{S_n = S}]
= 1 \cdot P(S_n < S) + 0 \cdot P(S_n = S).$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! "I'm a little confused by the definitions of $n$ and $S_n$, but it seems $S_n$ is the number of people that get to board the plane, and $n-S_n$ is the number of overbooked passengers that need to be compensated." Yes, that's exactly what $S_n$ and $n-S_n$ is. $n$ is the amount of sold tickets. Sorry if that was confusing and I didn't make it clear. I think you actually figured it out! The only thing that doesn't quite make sense to me yet, is the first point $$S_n <S \iff S_n=n<S$$

Comment: Ctd..It seems that this says: The fact that less people are on the flight than max capacity means that the amount of tickets sold were less than $S$. But couldn't it be for example that the airline sold $S$ tickets but one person didn't show up?

Comment: @Nullspace There is this sentence in the problem statement: "Assume if they don't show up to a flight they don't have to pay."

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thanks you so much again for your help and taking the the time to figure this out. I have been sitting at this for a few days not getting anywhere. (Also nice that my flying question was answered by an avian :))