# Maximize the Profit of an overbooked Airplane

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem

I am trying to solve the task

"Often the number of passengers on a flight is less than the number of bookings for that flight. The airline therefore overbooks with the risk of financially compensating any excess passengers. Assume that the airline has a revenue of 300 euros for each passenger flying with it, and a loss of 500 euros for each excess person who has booked a seat. Furthermore, each person who has booked a seat appears independently for the flight with probability p = 0.95. How many seats would you have at one

> Airbus A319 with S=124 seats

> Airbus A380 with S=555 seats

sell to maximize expected profit?

I did it like this, only with my values for S=124. But something is wrong. I know, that the expected value is 130 Seats.

[Central limit problem. Maximizing profit when overbooking flights.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4168304/central-limit-problem-maximizing-profit-when-overbooking-flights)

Here is my calculation:

$$P \left (\frac{S_{n}-0.95n}{\sqrt{0.95n(1-0.95)}}\leq{\frac{124-0.95n}{\sqrt{0.95n(1-0.95)}}} \right )\geq{\frac{500}{800}}$$

with a=300, b=500, S=124, p=0.95

$$\frac{S_{n}-0.95n}{\sqrt{0.95n(1-0.95)}}=X_{n}$$

Chat GPT says the Z-Score of $$\frac{500}{800}$$ is 0.5, but I know something is wrong, because n has to be 130

EDIT:

I got a new Z Score. The Z Score is 0.32

My Solution is:

Airbus A319 with S=124 seats: The Airline should sell 130 Seats

Airbus A380 with S=555 seats: The Airline should sell 582 Seats

Can someone please help me? :)

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adapt to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left`and `\right`.

Comment: ChatGPT does not perform any actual calculations when it gives an answer, so do not trust any numbers that it gives. You are better off using something like WolframAlpha.

Comment: Can you calculate the expected revenue with $130$ bookings (on the first plane) and with $129$ or $131$ bookings?

Comment: The expected revenue with 130 bookings is E(R)=n*p=S (p=0.95, S=124). We get n=130.526....The expected revenue with 129 bookings is n*p=S (p=0.95, S=123). We get n=129.473...The expected revenue with 131 bookings is n*p=S (p=0.95, S=125). We get n=131.578.... But how does it help me?

Comment: I calculated it with Wolfram Alpha. I think the problem is that I have the wrong Z-score? By the way I do not know how to calculate the Z-Score for 500/800

Comment: Sorry, the expected revenue for 130 Bookings is 130*300=39.000, the expected revenue for 129 Bookings is 129*300=38700 and the expected revenue for 131 Bookings is 131*300-1*500=38.800